# Getting the data of all the features on a layer in a map

Tags: javascript, angular, maps, openlayers, geoserver

So I'm building a project where I'm displaying a map with different layers on top of it. When I click on a specific polygon on a layer, I get the data of that polygon (basically the attributes table) using the
`getFeatureInfoUrl()` method and I display it by simply running a for loop.
Now I want to get the data of all the polygons on that layer. Is there a method to do that or am I just supposed to use the `getFeatureInfoUrl()` method?
I'm getting the data from a GeoServer and using the OpenLayers library.

```
var url = this.wmsSource.getFeatureInfoUrl(
        evt.coordinate,
        viewResolution,
        'EPSG:3857',
        {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'}
      );
```

This is the code for a specific polygon, and it just returns one feature. But this works for one specific coordinate only so I'm not sure how to move forward with this.
I could try the `FEATURE_COUNT: 1,` option but then I would have to specify manually how many features are there and it would still require me to click on the map. Want to get the data without clicking on the map.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all features from this code:

```html
vectorLayer.getSource()?.on('addfeature', function(evt:any){
          debugger
          var feature=evt.feature;
          })
```

Comment: So I am using TileWMS and TileLayer for creating the layers instead of Vector Source and because of that I get an error saying `Property 'getSource' does not exist on type 'TileWMS'.`